# Can't override Kubernetes config in Kubernetes Go client

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I want to use Kubernetes Go client to execute various actions in a cluster.
I am loading my local `kubeconfig` which contains multiple clusters and contexts. The default context is `prod` and one of the config values I want to override is the `CurrentContext`

```
    clientConfig := clientcmd.NewNonInteractiveDeferredLoadingClientConfig(
        &clientcmd.ClientConfigLoadingRules{ExplicitPath: "/Users/me/.kube/config"},
        &clientcmd.ConfigOverrides{
            CurrentContext: "stage",
        })

    rawConfig, _ := clientConfig.RawConfig()
    log.Printf(rawConfig.CurrentContext) // outputs "prod" instead of "stage"
```

When I inspect `RawConfig()` the current context is still "prod" instead of "stage".
Why does the config override not work?

Also how does the override for AuthInfo etc. work? The override accepts only a single `AuthInfo` whereas the configuration contains a map of `AuthInfo` etc.

GitHub related issue https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/735

Answer (score 6):

> Why does the config override not work?

according to

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/a432bd9ba7da427ae0a38a6889d72136bce4c4ea/tools/clientcmd/client_config.go#L57-L58

```golang
// ClientConfig is used to make it easy to get an api server client
type ClientConfig interface {
    // RawConfig returns the merged result of all overrides
    RawConfig() (clientcmdapi.Config, error)
```

`RawConfig` should return config with overrides, but it really doesn't

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/a432bd9ba7da427ae0a38a6889d72136bce4c4ea/tools/clientcmd/client_config.go#L122-L124

```golang
func (config *DirectClientConfig) RawConfig() (clientcmdapi.Config, error) {
    return config.config, nil
}
```

just return config without overrides. You could see a possible solution here in my patch

https://github.com/vvelikodny/kubernetes-client-go/pull/1/files

> Also how does the override for AuthInfo etc. work? The override accepts only a single AuthInfo whereas the configuration contains a map of AuthInfo etc.

override only AuthInfo with the key of username which presented in context.AuthInfo (string).

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/a432bd9ba7da427ae0a38a6889d72136bce4c4ea/tools/clientcmd/client_config.go#L424-L437

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/a432bd9ba7da427ae0a38a6889d72136bce4c4ea/tools/clientcmd/client_config.go#L388-L394

```golang
// getAuthInfoName returns a string containing the current authinfo name for the current context,
// and a boolean indicating  whether the default authInfo name is overwritten by a user-set flag, or
// left as its default value
func (config *DirectClientConfig) getAuthInfoName() (string, bool) {
    if len(config.overrides.Context.AuthInfo) != 0 {
        return config.overrides.Context.AuthInfo, true
    }
    context, _ := config.getContext()
    return context.AuthInfo, false
}
```